# Cannot connect Redis Cluster in Elasticache to React using REST API

Tags: reactjs, amazon-elasticache

I am currently building a React app and need to include a Redis cache. To do this, I have created an EC2 instance and a Redis Cache in ElastiCache. My next step is to access the Redis cluster via a REST API. I can connect to Redis via `redis-cli` from the EC2 instance, but I cannot use a lambda function for the Redis connection.

[image: My Idea]

Please help me to create an API like this.

I have attempted to implement an API with Node.js but have been unsuccessful in connecting to the Redis cluster.

Comment: Did you try this? https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonElastiCache/latest/mem-ug/Lambda.html

Comment: I cannot use lambda. I need to create an API without a lambda function